# Is every element in the cotangent space a differential of some smooth function?

Tags: differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds

Let $M$ be a smooth manifold and $T_p^*M$ be its cotangent space at $p$. I wonder if any element $w \in T_p^*M$ (a functional in $T_pM \to \mathbb R$) can be realized as the differential of a smooth function on $M$. i.e. $w=df_p$ for some $f:M\to \mathbb R$, smooth function.

For $X_p\in T_pM$, by definition
$$df_p(X_p)(g)=X_p(g\circ f), g\in C^\infty(\mathbb R).$$

I don't know how to find such an $f$ given $w$. Also, will this $f$ be independent of the choice of local coordinate?

Comment: Consider $w~=~\dfrac{-y}{x^2+y^2}dx+\dfrac{x}{x^2+y^2}dy, \qquad (x,y)~\in\mathbb{R}^2\backslash \{(0,0)\}.$

Comment: @Matematleta That's a good answer - but not to the question asked, I think. The answer is 'yes' if I understand the question correctly. For a fixed $p$, and a fixed $w\in T_p$, one can find a function locally with the desired properties, because one can do so in Euclidean space. Therefore, using a bump function, $f$ can be taken to be global. Agree?

Comment: @peterag Right I meant locally... but how can I find such a function?

Comment: @Matematleta This example makes some sense. Could you explain more? I forgot which theorems in multivariable calculus you are invoking here?

Comment: For fixed $w$. Take coordinate functions $x_1\cdots x_n$ around $p$ [so that $x_i(p)=0$]. Write $w = \sum w_i {dx_i}_p$, with $w_i\in {\mathbb R}$, which is possible because $\{{dx_i}_p\}$ forms a basis. Then the function $\tilde f=\sum w_i x_i$ makes sense locally, and $d\tilde f_p = w$. To make it defined globally, choose a function $\rho$ with a very small compact support, and equal to $1$ identically in a nhd of $p$. Take $f= \rho \tilde f$.

Comment: @peterag: maybe I am misreading the question, but if what you say is true, even locally, then every $1$-form is exact, which is of course, not true. For example, take $\omega$ as in my remark and integrate it around any circle of radius $\epsilon$ centered at the origin, You get $2\pi\epsilon,$  not zero.

Comment: @NoOne are you looking for something like this? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3263361/an-example-computation-with-a-form-that-is-closed-but-not-exact/3263482#3263482

Comment: @Matematleta Exactly! Thanks! I will read it

Comment: @Matematleta What are the $p$ and $M$ in your example? If $M=\mathbb R^2$ and $p=(0,0)$ then I am not sure that the $w$ you defined is in the cotangent space at $p$.

Comment: I also saw this https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2343742/can-every-linear-map-between-tangent-spaces-be-realized-as-a-differential-of-a-m?rq=1

Comment: @NoOne I am taking the punctured plane $M=\mathbb R^2\setminus \{0\}$ as my manifold (it is an open set in $\mathbb R^2$). Then, $\omega$ sends $p=(x,y)\in M$ to the cotangent bundle $p\mapsto \omega_{p}=\dfrac{-y}{x^2+y^2}dx+\dfrac{x}{x^2+y^2}dy$ where $dx$ and $dy$ are basis vectors for the cotangent space at $p$.

Comment: @Matematleta certainly every closed form is exact, locally (Poincare Lemma $H^k({\mathbb R}^n)=0, k>0$). But that was irrelevant in my argument. As I understood the question $w$ is a cotangent vector at $p$ - not a 1-form defined in some nhd (let alone globally). All I was arguing is that there exists an $f$ such that $df_p = w$, which really is a weak statement. In any case, $T_p^*$ is sometimes defined as $m_p/m_p^2$, where $m_p$ is the max'l ideal in the stalk at $p$ of ${\cal C}$, the sheaf of infinitely differentiable fns...   With that definition, the statement is almost a tautology.

Comment: @peterag: Yes, I agree with this. On a $contractible$ domain, you have Poincare. [This](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3263361/an-example-computation-with-a-form-that-is-closed-but-not-exact/3263482#3263482) post gives a good example of what can go wrong if the domain is not contractible.